# Check if current_user is included in active record relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am making an application using Ruby on Rails. I have a reservation model that has_many participants.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
Reservation.all.where("participants include ?", current_user)
```

Is it possible to do this and how?

I know I can switch it around and do:

```
current_user.reservations_as_participant
```

But, I am wondering if the other way around is also possible.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```rb
Reservation.joins(:participants).where(participants: { id: current_user.id })
```